# Unable to translate English to Chinese in php gettext internalization

Tags: php, internationalization, xampp, window, gettext

I currently trying to convert English to Chinese word. These is my code.

```
<?php
    $language = "zh_CN";
    putenv("LC_ALL=$language"); 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);
    $domain = "messages";
    bindtextdomain($domain, "Local"); 
    bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
    textdomain($domain);
    echo _("HELLO_WORLD");
?>
```

And this is the output. It should be displaying 你好世界! instead of Hello World!

I tested with English conversion and it working fine. But when I replace `$language = "en_US"` to `$language = "zh_CN"` and restart apache, it still showing the English translation word.

I got print the value of putenv and setlocale and get putenv = 1 and setlocal = empty.

I'm using

1. Window 10 single language.
2. Xampp 5.6.12
3. PHP Version 5.6.12

And this is my directory

```
Local----->en_US ----->LC_MESSAGES ----->messages.mo
                                   ----->messages.po
     ----->zh_CN ----->LC_MESSAGES ----->messages.mo
                                   ----->messages.po
```